# Babel compilation leads to: syntaxError: Unexpected token (38:4)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new in Node and React and I am getting this error when trying to build in Babel in order to upload the serverjs and react client to Heroku.

Everything is working fine in Postman but could not upload it to Heroku. After searching online, I found I have to compile it with Babel first.

The error message is:

```
SyntaxError: client/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/src/index.js: Unexpected token (38:4)
  36 | 
  37 |   return {
> 38 |     ...proto,
     |     ^
  39 |     ...api,
  40 |   };
  41 | }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Baraa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-21T16_14_47_767Z-debug.log
```

My webpack.config.js file contains:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: "./client/src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/public",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: ["react"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/name": "http://localhost:3011"
    }
  }
};



package.json
{
  "name": "app04",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "11.8.0"
  },
  "description": "app 04",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build-babel": "babel -d ./build ./ -s",
    "build": "npm run build-babel",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./build/server.js"
  },
  "author": "Baraa Rashad",
  "dependencies": {
    "accuweather": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "nvm": "0.0.4",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-json-pretty": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-config": "^4.4.0-beta.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "reactstrap": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  }
}



.babelrc
{
  "presets": ["env", "es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Baraa! I don't think you should give any `options` to the `babel-loader` if you have a `.babelrc` file. Try to remove the options and see if you get the same error. If that doesn't work you might need the [`babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread.html) plugin.

Comment: do you mean remove this option and install this plugin then try again ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adjusting the package.josn like following.

```js
  "scripts": {
    "devstart": "babel-node ./src/bin/www",
    "start": "npm run build && node ./build/bin/www",
    "build": "npm run babel-build",
    "babel-build": "babel -d ./build ./src -s",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
```